# Translated URL not found in Django app

Tags: django, internationalization

I have the following lines in URL config:

```
url(_(r'^foobar/(?P<foo_id>[0-9]+).pdf$'), fooBarPdf, name='show-foobar-pdf-view'),
url(_(r'^foobar/([0-9]+)/$'), fooBar, name='show-foobar-view'),
```

Now, I have also those URL-s nicely translated in the corresponding PO files, but the weird thing is, that for the second URL, the translated URL works, but for the first one it doesn’t. Yet, they both work perfectly fine for the EN default ones.

E.g.

```
example.com/foobar/100.pdf
example.com/foobar/100/
```

both return the expected content. But if I try to access the translated URL-s

```
example.com/et/estonian-translation-of-foobar/100.pdf
example.com/et/estonian-translation-of-foobar/100/
```

I only get the second one to work. The PDF one returns a 404.

Does anyone have a clue where to start to debug this? It does seem that the view method is not even called and I get sent directly to a 404. Reordering the url patterns doesn’t have any effect and all other translated URLs work fine.

Patterns from the .po file:

```
 #: my_app/urls.py:176
 msgid "^foobar/(?P<foo_id>[0-9]+).pdf$"
 msgstr "^estonian-translation-of-foobar/(?P<foo_id>[0-9]+).pdf$"

 #: my_app/urls.py:177
 msgid "^foobar/([0-9]+)/$"
 msgstr "^estonian-translation-of-foobar/([0-9]+)/$"
```

Comment: Where are the patterns that are matching the language codes?

Comment: They are in the .po files as every other translated URL pattern I’m using.